# Typescript Array find inside Array some

Tags: typescript

With this code below I've got an error that inform me that the object could be undefined, but if Array.some test pass then the find supposed to be defined right ?

I am missing something ?

The code :

```
if (attributes.some((a) => a.key === "my_key")) {
  my_key = checkout.attributes.find(
    (a) => a.key === "my_key"
  ).value;
}
```

I try to dig into typescript documentation but I did'nt find any revelant information.

Comment: Why search through the array twice? Just call `find` and do a null check on the result.

Comment: TS doesn't analyse the callback to verify that `arr.some(fn1)` and `arr.find(fn2)` would have an equivalent `fn1` and `fn2`. Or even more generally, doesn't try to do logical deductions between two different method calls.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` call doesn't know the implications of the surrounding conditional. If you want to make the assertion yourself, you can use the `as` keyword.

```
// assuming `attributes` is of some array `YourAttributeType[]`
if (attributes.some((a) => a.key === "my_key")) {
  my_key = checkout.attributes.find(
    (a) => a.key === "my_key"
  )?.value as YourAttributeType;
}
```

I suggest instead of iterating over the array twice with `some` and `find`, just call `find` once and handle an empty result yourself:

```
const entry = checkout.attributes.find(a => a.key === "my_key");
if (entry === undefined) return; // or throw, or set some default value etc.
// typescript should infer `entry` as a `YourAttributeType` at this point
const my_key = entry.value
```

Answer (score 0):

`Find` might return undefined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

So this is basically typescript being helpful.

If you don't mind the possibility that `my_key` can be set to undefined you can do this:

```
if (attributes.some((a) => a.key === "my_key")) {
  my_key = checkout.attributes.find(
    (a) => a.key === "my_key"
  )?.value;
}
```